# Mapping property values to conditions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, anti-patterns

I am new to WPF and C#. I have a button in my GUI that is presented as an image. However, the image displayed depends on certain conditions. Depending on the conditions, the button could be one of 5 images. I have coded it like this :

View:

```
<Button x:Name="bShow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Height="200" >
        <Image Source="{Binding myShowProp}"/>
```

Property myShowProp is defined in MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```
public string myShowProp // This property decides what image appears inside the button
{
    get { return privProp; }
    set 
    { 
        privProp = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("myShowProp");
    }
}
```

A routine called `SetButtonImage` is responsible for the logic that maps certain conditions to certain images. It is coded inside MainWindow.xaml.cs as :

```
private void SetButtonImage() 
{
     if ( /* condition1 */)
         myShowProp = image1;
     else if ( /* condition2 */)
         myShowProp = image2;
     else if ( /* condition3 */)
         myShowProp = image3;
     else if ( /* condition4 */)
         myShowProp = image4;
     else
         myShowProp = image5;

}
```

Can you show me a better way of doing the above, I don't imagine a ubiquitous use of `if` being the best design, seems like I am missing something.

Another motivation behind this is that I have a designer, and if this is something you could do in BLend, at control properties level, then I would rather have him do it in blend, instead of adding to the code-behind.

P.S. One of the things I am going to do is to refactor my existing code as per the MVVM paradigm.

Comment: You maybe be able to use a [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statment, but I imagine you're already aware. The problem is "Depending on the conditions, the button could be one of 5 images" ties you into this syntax. This could be legitimate need, or a symptom of bad design elsewhere, I can't comment.

Comment: Why don't you use styles to modify the button content to show image? Similar if conditions could be added as triggers to the style. Main intent of MVVM is to have least amount of code in code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is supposed to be used with the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern, which uses concepts as DataBinding (already in use) and Templating, more specifically the use (on Buttons) of ControlTemplates with Triggers.

The idea would be:

- You would have five ImageSources, declared in Button.Resources;
- You would have an Enum property (not a String!) on your ViewModel;
- Your button would have a DataTemplate containing an Image;
- The Image's Source would be defined by a series of triggers bound to that Enum property.

Comment: Thanks. What are Button.Resources, I don't see it in documentation.

Comment: Every WPF Control (buttons, panels, labels, etc.) can have a property called `Resources`, which is a dictionary containing resources for that control. Common resources would be Styles, DataTemplates, ImageSources, etc. Just google around and you'll easily find lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Long If-Else statements are necessary when you have complex conditions. If it's multiple states of a single condition then a switch statement would simplify it for you. Just make sure that you're calling SetButtonImage() in the setters for any properties that are used in those conditions and it'll be fine.

Is the myShowProp property just supplying an image address for the button's  to get the picture? If so, that's a place that you can change things to be more in line with MVVM. You want the property to just give the state, preferably a name descriptive of the state, that your GUI designer will then use to determine the image. He'll be able to use resources and possibly style triggers to display the correct image.

I've been working with MVVM for over a year now, I think I'm doing a decent job of it, and the code you posted looks fine to me.